# What can speed up Windows shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, windows-services

What steps can I take to speed up the shutdown of my Windows 7 workstation? I have tried setting to 0 the *ClearPageFileAtShtudown* registry setting with some improvement. Here is the rest of the information.

My Windows workstation is a laptop with 8GB RAM running Windows 7. The laptop hardware is a Thinkpad T520.

My workstation runs Visual Studio 2012, its programs, and developer edition of MS SQL Server well. My workstation also boots up in a reasonable amount of time.

However, my workstation takes a very long time to log out, let alone to shutdown.

Even shutting down SQL server components some minutes before logging out does not help. Logging out each night, seems to decrease log out/shutdown time.

Is there anything else I can do to speed up Windows shutting down?

Comment: What is running as it shuts down.  There is some process or processes that is causing the performance issue.  Is the desktop displayed?  Could be an AV thing (I've seen some AV software check file integrity on shutdown like they sometimes do on startup).  It could be a scheduled task that runs on shutdown/logoff.

Comment: When I try to shutdown, Visual Studio and SQL Server services are already shutdown. The normal desktop services are running, but nothing special is running.

Comment: In Control Panel > Performance Information and tools > Advanced Tools is there anything listed under "Performance issues"?  If you log in in Safe Mode, does it logoff and shutdown as expected?  If you log in as a new user does it logout and/or shutdown any quicker?

Comment: No Performance Issues.

Comment: Verify that your PC is not trying to clear the page file on shutdown. There's a local GP that can be set that will do that.

Comment: There are so many possibilities for this delay; program, process or driver. We are going to have a hard time giving you a definitive answer here. Check out this [article](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/227117-slow-shut-down.html) at Seven Forums, especially #6, which has some links to useful tutorials to help resolve this.

Comment: @MDTGuy Please answer using your comment and these links http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314834#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways and http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/244/

Comment: capture shutdown trace with *xbootmgr*, share the tarce and I can tell you what is slow: http://pastebin.com/RFRkuc81

Comment: Don't forget to look at your windows services! Starting with Vista, a service can now [request more time to gracefully shut down](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164252.aspx#S2) - potentially indefinitely. Maybe one of these is in play.

Comment: @Techie007 Nothing listed under Performance Issues.

Comment: Instead of troubleshooting it, here's a tip:  `REGEDIT` then go to `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management` - find the key `ClearPageFile at Shutdown`  and set it to 0.  It can make a big difference.  Also, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control` - find key `WaitToKillServiceTimeout` and set it to 1000.  Those two changes may change your mind about asking why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance is improved using this comment

> Verify that your PC is not trying to clear the page file on shutdown.
>   There's a local GP that can be set that will do that. –  MDT Guy

and these links helped.

[support.microsoft.com/kb/314834#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314834#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways)

[pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/244](http://pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/244)

I will also look at the other suggestions that were in the comments to improve performance.

Comment: you don't really ask a question, so I voted to close. Give me a shutdown trace if you have an issue, what you want currently want is speculations

Comment: @magicandre1981 and I reasked question in title with a little more info.

Comment: it is still and will always be offtopic. You don't ask any real question. Slow shutdown can be a lot of things, which can only discovered via capturing a shutdown trace.

Comment: I asked what can be done.

Comment: and I told you several times that this can be caused by a lot of issues (hanging service, buggy driver which causes DPC issues) which can be only DISCOVERED by doing a shutdown trace.

Comment: @magicandre1981 And as I noted, fixing the clear page file improved the condition.